# mapping but getting error Uncaught TypeError: dataList.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Hello i have a MERN project, this is my first time using mongodb. So i want to get the data by id and map the data. but i kept getting error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: dataList.map is not a function
    at HistoryDetail (HistoryDetail.js:216:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

the data is fine in the console and network. Is this the problem with how i mapping the data or wrong format ? idk.

this is the data in console and network :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1025606524099383326/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1025606569896988682/unknown.png

this is the front end code :

```
 const [ dataList, setDataList ] = useState([]);
 const getData = () => {
      Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/registration/${id}`).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setDataList(response.data)
      });
    };

   useEffect(() => {
      userExpire();
      getData();
    }, [])

  <div className='flexbox-container'>
          <div className='flexbox-item flexbox-item-1'>
            {dataList.map((val, index) => {
            return (
            <div className="leftDiv" key={index}>
              <h2 className='textSupplier'>Supplier Data</h2>
                <div className='textData'>
                  <p>Company Name : {val.CompanyName}</p>
                  <p>Address: {val.Address}</p>
                  <p>Phone Number : {val.PhoneNumber}</p>
                  <p>President Director (Name) : {val.PresidentName}</p>
                  <p>Account Manager (Email / Phone) : {val.AccountManagerEmail} / {val.AccountManagerPhone}</p> 
                  <p>Escalation PIC (Email / Phone) : {val.PICEmail} / {val.PICPhone}</p> 
                  <p>Established Date :   {moment(val.EstablishedDate).format("DD MMMM YYYY")} </p>
                  <p>Main Business : {val.MainBusiness}</p>
                  <p>Employee Number : {val.EmployeeNumber}</p>
                  <p>Number of Customer : {val.NumberOfCustomer}</p>
                  <p>Attachments : {val.Attachments}</p>
                  <p>ID : {val._id}</p>
                </div>
            </div>     
            )})}
          </div>
```

backend :

```
app.get("/registration/:id", (req, res) => {
    const Id = req.params.id;
    
    DataModel.findById({_id : Id}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }else {
            res.send(result)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It is an object so the method 'map' doesn't exist, seeing your data it is not needed to map at all, just remove and directly put as `{dataList.prop_names}` ... Map is for elements in an array

Comment: it makes sense ty. im so confused

Comment: No worries  happens

Comment: your response is an `object`, so mapping doesn't work. If you got this error this means that something is wrong with data you mapping. To check what is wrong you can check type by logging `typeof`, in this case `typeof dataList`. You will see that `dataLists` type isn't `array` but `object`, so mapping isn't possible